# How can I calculate the sums of all possible combinations of elements of a set? [Python]

Tags: list, combinations, combinatorics

For example, I have the list `L = [1,2,4]`. For the sake of comprehension, I want to list all the combinations for two pulls with a put back (the order does not matter):

```
[1,1]
[1,2]
[2,2]
[1,4]
[2,4]
```

The sum of the respective lists is then: [2,3,4,5,6].

So I want to get the output [2,3,4,5,6] from the input [1,2,4] with a function, so to speak. In the general case, the list has k elements and N elements are taken for the combinations. Say:

```
def fun(L,N):
    ... 
    (do the thing)
    return sum_list
```

Answer (score 0):

something like below

```
L = [1, 2, 4]
k = []
for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(len(L)-i):
        k.append(L[j+i] + L[i])
```

Comment: But that would only be the case for N = 2. So theoretically I would have to write N for loops (recursively?), which would completely explode the runtime. Is there perhaps an implementation via a package? I once read something about combn, where you could do something similar with the attribute sum. But I don't think this was updated anymore.